# Benchmarking and Monitoring in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, benchmarking, monitor

I am trying to run a benchmark and monitor the cpu frequency while the benchmark is running. What would be the best method to do this in the smallest footprint possible?

Basicly, I have a benchmark I want to run and a scripted while loop that polls a cpu register for data and calculates the cpu frequency. When the benchmark terminates, I want the while loop to terminate as well. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: To elaborate more clearly, I want the while loop to continue polling. Say this task is assigned to a particular core on a cpu, I want that core to also be available to the benchmark.

Mainly, I want the benchmark to run as if the polling loop isn't there and to exhibit the same behavior. If there are four cores, I do not want the benchmark to only use three since the while loop is assigned to the other core.

Answer (score 2):

Preface: I'm a computer science STUDENT.
My understanding is you have two programs written in python and you want to run both programs simultaneously. How that is handled if you just run both programs is decided by the operating system.  However you can use threading to manually control access to the resources you need.

Python docs on threading: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

If you are using a garden variety *nix distro you can add & to the end of the command to execute them in the background.  The OS will take over from there, treating your while() script as just another program running beside the benchmark. (Much like playing solitaire while you wait)

```
python myBenchamrk.py &
python myWhile.py &
```

I'm fairly confident the above applies to mac OS X as well (Maybe it counts as a *nix system?)
I'm certain that Windows has the equivalent.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Ive found a different method using subprocess but I will give yours a shot if it dose not work.